# Can the new Azure Preview Portal deploy custom VM?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Is there a way to deploy a custom VM in the preview portal?  I'm trying to migrate to the new DS series, but the only images I can deploy are the default ones azure provides.

Comment: If your VM is already in Azure you can just scale up to the DS series. Browse to your machine in the new portal > Settings > Size > Select the size you want.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way, however it will require you to write your own ARM template. Once you have your own ARM template with the custom VM, you can deploy it using the gallery item "Template deployment" under Compute.

To see an example of an ARM template that uses a custom VM (i.e. a custom VHD image) see https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-from-user-image. Note that the template can be delivered via a hyperlink as the "Deploy to Azure" button is doing: https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template/uri/YOUR-TEMPLATE-URL-HERE.

[image: Template deployment]

Answer (score 1):

To deploy a saved/custom VM image in the new Azure portal, from the left menu of the portal click "More Services > VM images (classic)". From there you can select your custom VM image and choose the option to "Create VM".

Comment: This answer should be marked as the correct one. It works and exactly answers the question.